Django objects.filter returns empty array even it returns an object before with same request
I'm currently working on an Excel to DB Project, where I put 3000 products into my SQLite DB. Some of the products are duplicated or already exist in the DB. So, I am looping through the Excel sheet and checking with:
# Check if "Produkt" already Exists. If it does, return the id of the "Produkt" 
produkt = Produkt.objects.filter(**{"name": produktName})
p_serializer = ProduktSerializer(produkt, many=True)

with:
if len(p_serializer.data) == 0:

I am checking if the product already exists.
My main problem now is that it may detect the first product, but skip the next one (for example, if the same product appears three times in a row) and just return [].
I thought about race conditions, but that should not be possible cause I'm the only one accessing the application right now.
I tried time-outing the loop, but this didn't help. I also tried to tell the if statement:
if len(p_serializer.data) == 0 and lastItem != produktName:

Also didn't work.
EDIT:
This is what I get when I print the request for one of the products:

<QuerySet [<Produkt: Produkt object (40)>, <Produkt: Produkt object (279)>, <Produkt: Produkt object (385)>, <Produkt: Produkt object (614)>]>
<QuerySet []>
2362
<QuerySet []>
2363
<QuerySet []>
2364

The first one finds a lot of the same products and after that I only get empty QuerySets. (the numbers are the ids of the newly created products).

After the product has been found from the excel files, what are you doing in the code? are you deleting products that have been found?
